# My new MacBook Pro won't keep its Wi-Fi connection

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos, airport

Here's the deal... I have relatively brand new Macbook pro, I purchased it in late June 2014 and right now it's November 2014. Recently, my Macbook will not keep an internet connection to wifi. There's no problem with the router; I've had no trouble with my iPhone or PC's or even other Macbooks in this house. Additionally, I've noticed the same problem with my computer in other networks, but I can't offer too much information about that, because 99% of the time I have my computer in my house.

More details:

- There is no pattern for this loss of connectivity. I cannot stay connected more than 15 minutes, and it fluctuates between about 10 and 2 minutes, usually. The time does not change with my activity or lack thereof on the internet.
- I have tried things like clearing all my wifi passwords and networks, changing my location in network settings, turning off the wifi connection, restarting, and all of these things separately and together. Nothing changes.
- I first noticed this about a week or two after upgrading to OSX Yosemite (10.10). But it was nothing simultaneous and I've heard of similar problems on other OS's, so I personally can't point my finger to that problem.
- My Airport Utility is `6.3.4 (634.17)` and the card is AirPort Extreme `(0x14E4, 0xF5)`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I bought this computer to last me 5 years as I study abroad and complete 4 years of college. Right now, I just really need some assurance that I didn't spend 8 months of paychecks on an $1800 aluminum frisbee.

Went to Apple Store today (Dec. 27 2014).also family members have iPads, other Mac Pros, iPhones…NO NETWORK PROBLEMS except with single Mac Pro .Apple absolutely no help…..blames the network (which it is not)….and said, work it out with Internet Provider or if you don't believe us pay for tech help (as unit is out of warranty)…That, itself was an amazing experience.If anyone finds an answer I would appreciate the help as well.

Comment: you should look in to your Console log to see what is disconnecting it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer using the Recovery HD and then seeing if it stays connected?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on OS X 10.10.1? It claims to fix some wifi issues present in 10.10.0.

If your software is up to date, you can try the following steps. They worked perfectly on my early 2011 MBP running Yosemite. [Source](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/)

1. Turn off Wi-Fi from the menu bar.
2. From Finder, hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or click Go > Go to Folder) and enter the following path:

   ```
   /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
   ```
3. Within this folder, locate and select the following files. (Note: You may not actually have all of them. I know I didn't have all five files on my computer, but I deleted all the ones I had and the fix still worked!)

   ```
   com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
   com.apple.network.identification.plist
   com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
   NetworkInterfaces.plist
   preferences.plist
   ```
4. Move them to a backup folder, like on your desktop. The goal is to delete them from the SystemConfiguration folder (so make sure they don't exist in that folder any more!) to force OS X to recreate them, but you'll want to be able to put your original files back in there in case something goes wrong.
5. Reboot your computer.
6. Turn on Wi-Fi from the menu bar. Good luck!

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Your product is still under Apple warranty.

Best course of action is to bring it to Apple Store for service.

It sounds like hardware problem anyway.

Meanwhile you could try some troubleshooting, like start in safe mode and see if it works.

Next try logging in as another user to see if it is your user profile related.

Also you could delete your airport plist in your user Library file and reboot.

Added Dec. 27 2014:

Run a continuous Ping to see if it keeps its connection.

In Terminal type `ping -i 60 google.com`
 and let it run for a hour. (it will send a ping to Google every 60 seconds).

The continuous Ping will do following:

Test your connection to your router, test your connection from router to Google (which is actualy testing your Internet provider). The result will give you some inside on what is going on.